# I can connect to AWS MySQL RDS instance from workbench but not in my JDBC application

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-web-services, jdbc

I am trying to create a Java application that connects to a MySQL database and I am using AWS to host it. So I created the AWS RDS instance and I got it to connect to the MySQL workbench just fine. My problem arises when I am trying to use JDBC to connect to it.

I have security groups that allow traffic from anywhere, but I also tried just allowing my IP. 
I had it working when I was using a localhost but now I'm trying to move it to a server so keeping it localhost isn't an option (used localhost to test the application and such)
I made sure that my user was a remote user by doing

```
SELECT * from mysql.user;
```

And made sure that the host was a '%' and that it had all the privileges

So my code I'm trying to connect with in Java is

```java
String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql:/{hostname}:{port}/{database name}/?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false";
String username = "username";
String password = "password";
con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, username, password);
```

Of course I have the actual host, port, and such in there just changed it for posting online.

When I try running it on Eclipse it says this java.lang.Exception: Database not found
I looked up some tutorials on AWS docs to make sure it lined up, which it all did.
Anyone have any idea why it might be connecting to MySQL workbench and not the JDBC?

Comment: Did you add jdbc driver(jar file)?

Comment: Possible typo in `jdbc:mysql:/{hostname}` - should be `jdbc:mysql://{hostname}` - and are you sure you aren't using ssl?

Comment: The exception you mention doesn't sound like a standard exception. Please provide a [mre] and make sure to post the full exception stacktrace. And as Elliott Frisch indicated, you have a typo in your URL.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch ah yeah good catch thank you, somehow deleted that at somepoint.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel that's actually all it was saying plus the line it was failing to connect at. Found out if I took the SSL out and fixed my typo it connected. It's giving me an error about SSL now though. Going to try to figure out why it's giving me that. However it connects fine though.

Comment: And that is why we want complete exception stacktraces, so we can know where it originated and what its causes were.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel yeah I understand that but I gave the complete error that Eclipse was giving. I would have given more but it's all I had haha.